# Python - Using requests sends post message

Tags: python, python-requests, postman

I used Postman to send a raw request to Jetstar website to get the flight details. And I wanted to use python script to do the same thing using requests library, but I cannot get back the correct response.

Here what I have done in Postman:

[image]

And a simple script I used to send post request:

```
import requests
files = {'file': open('PostContent.txt', 'rb')}
if __name__ == "__name__"):
    url = "http://www.jetstar.com/"
    r = requests.post(url, files = files)
    print(r.text)
```

When I run the python script, I always get the welcome page not flight details. I am not sure what is error?

Note: The PostContent.txt contains the form-data in raw text when I search for flights.

I used Chrome Dev Tool to capture the POST request when I search for a specific flight date. And it is the Form Data in the Headers.
[image]

Comment: What's  the content of `PostContent.txt`?

Comment: Hi @PabloSantaCruz, I just edited my question, hope it's clearer for you!

Comment: Please post the PostContent.txt as text.

Comment: Maybe try to encode the POST data with `urllib.urlencode(files)`; if that doesn't work, open a packet analyzer like wireshark and inspect what the data looks like that's being sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a dictionary instead of a FILE. The FILE is supposed to be for posting a FILE, not a FORM-ENCODED post, which is probably what the site expects.

```
payload = {
   'DropDownListCurrency': 'SGD'
}
r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)
```

Comment: Yup, you are right, @Pablo! But do you know how to convert a text file to dict in python? Cause I am quite new to Python as well!

Answer (score 2):

You use a key `file` which is wrong for this type of request. Also your sample code isn't working! Just paste working code here...

```
import requests
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

payload = {"__EVENTTARGET":"",
"__EVENTARGUMENT":"",
"__VIEWSTATE":"/wEPDwUBMGQYAQUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFgEFJ01lbWJlckxvZ2luU2VhcmNoVmlldyRtZW1iZXJfUmVtZW1iZXJtZSDCMtVG/1lYc7dy4fVekQjBMvD5",
"pageToken":"",
"total_price":"",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$RadioButtonMarketStructure":"RoundTrip",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMarketOrigin1":"Nadi (NAN)",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMarketDestination1":"Melbourne (Tullamarine) (MEL)",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextboxDepartureDate1":"14/01/2015",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextboxDestinationDate1":"16/02/2015",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListCurrency":"AUD",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMarketOrigin2":"",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMarketDestination2":"",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextboxDepartureDate2":"16/02/2015",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextboxDestinationDate2":"",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMarketOrigin3":"",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMarketDestination3":"",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextboxDepartureDate3":"27/12/2014",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextboxDestinationDate3":"",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMarketOrigin4":"",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMarketDestination4":"",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextboxDepartureDate4":"03/01/2015",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextboxDestinationDate4":"",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMarketOrigin5":"",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMarketDestination5":"",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextboxDepartureDate5":"10/01/2015",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextboxDestinationDate5":"",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMarketOrigin6":"",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMarketDestination6":"",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextboxDepartureDate6":"17/01/2015",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextboxDestinationDate6":"",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListPassengerType_ADT":1,
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListPassengerType_CHD":0,
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListPassengerType_INFANT":0,
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$RadioButtonSearchBy":"SearchStandard",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMultiCityOrigin1":"Origin",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMultiCityDestination1":"Destination",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextboxDepartureMultiDate1":"",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMultiCityOrigin2":"Origin",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextBoxMultiCityDestination2":"Destination",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$TextboxDepartureMultiDate2":"",
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListMultiPassengerType_ADT":1,
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListMultiPassengerType_CHD":0,
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$DropDownListMultiPassengerType_INFANT":0,
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$numberTrips":2,
"ControlGroupSearchView$AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView$ButtonSubmit":""}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "http://booknow.jetstar.com/Search.aspx"
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
    print(r.text)
```

Comment: Hi @wenzul, how did you get the payload dictionary? Did you hard code it or you used any script to create it?

Comment: May it is working with scrapy. Don't know. Just copy the content and insert the quote via regex.